# Fullcalendar: How to events feed using JSON Service

Tags: java, json, fullcalendar, jira, jira-rest-java-api

Below is my calendar stuff in velocity template:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'User Issues',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                                 ....
                        }
              editable: true,
        events:
 "http://localhost:2990/rest/issuesrestresource/1.0/message/RetrieveAllIssuesForUser"


});
```

Below is Rest Resource Service stuff - JSON - RetrieveAllIssuesForUser method used for events feed:

```
@GET
@AnonymousAllowed
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("/RetrieveAllIssuesForUser")
public Response getAllIssueData()
{   
final List<IssuesRestResourceModel> issuesRestResourceModelList = new     ArrayList<IssuesRestResourceModel>();
final com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User  u =  authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser();
ao.executeInTransaction(new TransactionCallback() // (1)
{           
    @Override
    public List<IssuesRestResourceModel> doInTransaction()
    {
        ///fetching issues from activeobjects and preparing list of 
 IssuesRestResourceModel.
        }
        return null;
    }
});
return Response.ok(issuesRestResourceModelList.toArray()).build();
}
```

My IssueRestResourceModel has following properties to retrieved:

```
  @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private String message;

@XmlAttribute
private String key;

@XmlAttribute
private String start;

@XmlAttribute
private String end;

@XmlAttribute
private String issues;

@XmlAttribute
private String user = "";
```

Above code works correctly while retrieve events through Jquery. But events are not feed while provided events URL as shown above - events: "localhost/.../REstresourcemethod"

Can you suggest what is wrong here so, events not feeding.

Thank You